# How to get old Value with onchange() event in text box

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a text input. A value is populated into it when the page loads. If the user changes anything in text box, then I want to get the changed value (the new value) and old value. But calling `ELEMENT.value` it only returns the changed/new value.

How do I get the old value?

Here is my code:

```html
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function onChangeTest(changeVal) {
            alert("Value is " + changeVal.value);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
          <div>
              <input type="text" id="test" value ="ABS" onchange="onChangeTest(this)">  
          </div>
        </form>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`element.defaultValue` will give you the original value.

**Please note that this only works on the initial value.**

If you are needing this to persist the "old" value every time it changes, an expando property or similar method will meet your needs

Comment: just a note. I discovered on firefox element.getAttribute("value") also seems to reveal the original... I don't know enough to tell if this is a cross-browser/standard thing.

Comment: element.defaultValue returns the value set in the <input> tag. If this value has changed by editing or some other JavaScript, element,defaultValue will not return this (new) old value.

Comment: Thanks SabreWolfy, spotted your comment and solved my problem.  Had to change the value multiple times so doing the above was no good.

Answer (score 206):

You'll need to store the old value manually.  You could store it a lot of different ways.  You could use a javascript object to store values for each textbox, or you could use a hidden field (I wouldn't recommend it - too html heavy), or you could use an expando property on the textbox itself, like this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="onChangeTest(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" />
```

Then your javascript function to handle the change looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onChangeTest(textbox) {
        alert("Value is " + textbox.value + "\n" + "Old Value is " + textbox.oldvalue);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The change that was suggested here is incorrect.  First of all, once an alert occurs, the field has lost focus.  Any change after that would occur after the onfocus event was fired.  Second, the input field's onchange event doesn't fire until its lost focus.

Comment: This works better if you're manipulating the value multiple times.  The answer above (element.defaultValue) only works once. Up this one :)

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams I understood what you are doing.. I have a question: doesn't it should be `onchange="this.oldvalue = this.value;onChangeTest(this);"` What I means first assign value then call function ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No.  We're setting the old value on focus.  After that, after every change, we set it again.

Comment: A more precise and better answer, since the user can change the value of a textbox multiple times so we need to revert it at every instance

Comment: <select onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="onChangeTest(this.oldvalue);" />

This works for me on select tag

Comment: at least in firefox, onfocus is skipped in a number field when you directly click on a directional arrow to change the number. onchange fires, causing oldvalue to be undefined. this messy workaround seems to work: onchange="if(typeof this.oldValue == \'undefined\'){this.oldValue=this.defaultValue;}callSomeFn(this.value, this.oldValue);this.oldValue=this.value;"

Comment: Use [`data` attributes](/q/30417852/4642212) and [`dataset`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or [`Map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (storing _Element → old value_) instead of storing an arbitrary property on elements.

Answer (score 7):

You should use HTML5 data attributes. You can create your own attributes and save different values in them.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest:

```
function onChange(field){
  field.old=field.recent;
  field.recent=field.value;

  //we have available old value here;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A dirty trick I somtimes use, is hiding variables in the 'name' attribute (that I normally don't use for other purposes):

```
select onFocus=(this.name=this.value) onChange=someFunction(this.name,this.value)><option...
```

Somewhat unexpectedly, both the old and the new value is then submitted to `someFunction(oldValue,newValue)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this: add oldvalue attribute to html element, add set oldvalue when user click. Then onchange event use oldvalue.

```
<input type="text" id="test" value ="ABS" onchange="onChangeTest(this)" onclick="setoldvalue(this)" oldvalue="">

<script>
function setoldvalue(element){
   element.setAttribute("oldvalue",this.value);
}

function onChangeTest(element){
   element.setAttribute("value",this.getAttribute("oldvalue"));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to save the old value with the "onfocus" event to afterwards compare it with the new value with the "onchange" event.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but maybe this logic would work.

```
var d = 10;
var prevDate = "";
var x = 0;
var oldVal = "";
var func = function (d) {
    if (x == 0 && d != prevDate && prevDate == "") {
        oldVal = d;
        prevDate = d;
    }
    else if (x == 1 && prevDate != d) {
        oldVal = prevDate;
        prevDate = d;
    }
    console.log(oldVal);
    x = 1;
};
/*
         ============================================
         Try:
         func(2);
         func(3);
         func(4);
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the previous value of the textbox into a hidden textbox. Then you can get the first value from hidden and the last value from textbox itself. An alternative related to this, at onfocus event of your textbox set the value of your textbox to an hidden field and at onchange event read the previous value.

Comment: But, If we have some 100+ text boxes, in this case we need to have 100+ hidden variables, So is there any other way we can get old values?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but as a workaround, tried in **ReactJS** with **Material-UI (MUI)**. For a **text input** and using the **onChange** method, the **initial value** gets stored into:

```
event.srcElement._wrapperState.initialValue
```

And the **previous value** gets stored into:

```
event.target.attributes.value.value
```

The **new value** can be extracted as standard from:

```
event.target.value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, I am sharing this for knowledge.

What I did so far is that I use element.defaultValue to get the old value, now the defaultValue always returns the value that was set in the value attribute, so when you do a successful change, just store the new value in the element value attribute:

```
element.setAttribute('value', [new value]);
```

Now what's interesting, is that element.defaultValue now returns the set value, and if for any reason you want to return to the old value before doing this setAttribute, you simply:

```
element.value = element.defaultValue;
```