# How to get old value and new value from input type text

Tags: javascript, html

How to get old value and new value from input type text;

```
<input type="text" name="quantity-row_111" value="1" id="quantity-row_111" onchange="myfunction(id);">

function myfunction(id){
     var oldvalue = getoldvalue();
     var newvalue = getnewvalue();
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what did you mean by `old` and `new` value? and also where is your `getoldvalue()` and `getnewvalue()` function?

Comment: And what do you mean by "old" value, the previous typed in value, or the value given in the attribute ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get old Value with onchange() event in text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box)

Comment: You should pick an answer, you are still an active user but no correct answer has been chosen.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

### HTML

```
 <input type="text" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="onChangeTest(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" />
```

### JavaScript

```
function onChangeTest(textbox) {
      console.log("New value: " + textbox.value + "\n" + "Old value: " + textbox.oldvalue);
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box)

Answer (score 2):

You may add another attribute (prevvalue) in your input fields like so:

```js
function myfunction(id){
  var oldvalue = id.getAttribute("prevvalue");
  var newvalue = id.value;
  alert(oldvalue);
  alert(newvalue);
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="quantity-row_111" value="1" prevvalue="4.50" id="quantity-row_111" onchange="myfunction(this);">
```

Then you have access to both values whenever any change occurs.
You will need to either pre-populate the old value or update it whenever the new value changes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If your element id is quantity-row_111, you can get the original value  and the new value by :

```
console.log("new value="+ document.getElementById('quantity-row_111').value  ); 
console.log("Original value="+ document.getElementById('quantity-row_111').defaultValue);
```

Look at the console log for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the newvalue saved as your oldvalue. This might be what you what you want,

```
var oldvalue = document.getElementById("quantity-row_111").value;
var newvalue;
function myfunction(id){
    alert(oldvalue);
    newvalue = document.getElementById("quantity-row_111").value;
    oldvalue = newvalue;
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/s11x91ax/)

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var OldValue;
        $("form :input").click(function () {
            var field= ($(this).attr('name'));
            OldValue= ($(this).attr('field'));
        })


        $("form :input").change(function () {
            var field = ($(this).attr('name'));
            var value = ($(this).attr('value'));
            console.log('Field:: ' + field + '\nNew Value: ' + value + '\nOld Value: ' + OldValue+'\n--------------------\n');

        })
    })
```