# onchanged event, get value prior to changing? in html input tag (type=range)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, html-input

Is there a way to extract the value of an input tag prior to input change at the `onchange` event? Or is there an event triggered before 'change' instead?
In particular I need it for type range.

This question adds to previously asked similar questions because I also
ask if there is NO way to 'catch' the value before it is being changed as
in many other programming languages.

```html
    <form >
      <input type="range" value="0" id="indentA" name="indentA" min="-20" max="20" onchange="alert('trying to output original value here... \ncurrent value is: '+this.value);" >
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value of select (dropdown) before change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change)

Comment: Please see edited question to see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the one you are looking? 
I am capturing the old value when the slider changes.
Please have a look at the below code snippet.

> Code Snippet

```js
var previos_value=0;
function getValue(value){
  
  alert('current value is: '+value);
  alert('Previous value is: '+previos_value);
  
  
  previos_value=value;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
  <input type="range" value="0" id="indentA" name="indentA" min="-20" max="20" onchange="getValue(this.value)" >
 </form>
```

Comment: is there no event to trigger just before change is complete?

Comment: I dont think so there will be any event of such kind.As of my knowledge "NO" there wont be any such event.