# Passing a value into a function jquery ?

Tags: jquery, onchange

which is the correct way to pass element_old to the element.change function?

```
  $('body').on('click', 'input', function(){
      element = $(this);
      element_old = element.val();

      element.change( function(element_old){
        if($(this).val() != element_old){ show button}
        else{ hide button }           

      })

    });
```

I want to show a button only if the input value has changed from its original value.

Comment: You can't. `onchange` is an event handler which is called on the element which raised the event

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box)

Comment: What re you trying to achive here? this smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ok tnx :) 
I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code

**HTML:**

```
<input  id="txtCustom" data-defaultText="Hello" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#txtCustom").on('input',function(){
    var self=$(this);
    var changedValue=self.val();
    var defaultValue=self.attr("data-defaultText");

    if(changedValue==defaultValue){
     //  Hide buttob
    }else {
     // show butto=n
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution works fine for me :)

```
  $('body').on('change', 'input', function(e){
      var x = $( '#q' ).prop( 'defaultValue' );
      if(x!=$( '#q' ).val() ){
       show button;
      }
    });
```