# VueJs - Method with old and new value of input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

TEMPLATE :

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" @change="get_values($event)" v-model="value" required />
```

STATE :

```
data(){
  return {
    value: ""
  }
}
```

METHOD :

```
get_values (event) {
   var value = event.target.value
}
```

I get the current value but i didn't find how to get the old value when i add +1 in my input

Any ideas ?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I ask if you know how to get an old value (for exemple i have a number 2 i add one and it return to me (2 and 3) because old and new

Comment: add a watcher to value

Comment: if watcher is not an option, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197822/vuejs-get-old-value-when-on-change-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs get old value when on change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197822/vuejs-get-old-value-when-on-change-event)

Comment: yes i already have seen but not really

Comment: @LucasLaurens Can you explain the not really part?

Comment: actually my value is in a loop so i can't really add a watcher this is like return { data: [{value: ' ' }] } so i tried with a method. this an array so i need to create a loop for each value in array

Comment: @LucasLaurens Sounds like we need more code in your question to explain your specific need.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fa0m9ktd/

Comment: I tried the same things with computed i think it's correct

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the old value whenever the input is updated, use a watcher, you don't need to listen to events:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            value: ""
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("You now have the new value: ", newValue, "and the old value: ", oldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible with a method ?

Comment: Not really. You should use a `watcher` as it is specifically designed for the use-case you have (you need to observe changes in a value and perhaps differences between those changes)

Comment: ok thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a v-model with a `set()` `get()` methods. This will allow a lot of flexibility in how the values are set. It will allowing you to set the data to something other than what was entered based on conditions:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      value: ""
    }
  },
  computed:{
    values: {
      get(){return this.value},
      set(v){
        console.log('old:', this.value)
        // loop values -- only allow 0-9
        this.value = v < 10 ? v : 0
        console.log('new:', this.value)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control"  v-model="values" required />
 </div>
```

Comment: i'll try thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a watcher:

```
data(){
  return {
     value: ""
  }
},
watch: {
   value:function(newValue, oldValue){
      console.log(newValue)
      console.log(oldValue)
   }
}
```

its important that the watch method has the same name as your `value` defined in the data properties.

Comment: is it possible with a method ?

Comment: what do you want to achive, maybe i can help you if i know ur problem

Comment: actually my value is in a loop so i can't really add a watcher this is like return { data: [{value: ' ' }] } so i tried with a method

Comment: @LucasLaurens What kind of a loop?

Comment: i still dont know what you want to achive

Comment: this an array so i need to create a loop for each value in array

Answer (score 1):

You can also use getter and setter:

```
data(){

    return {
      value_: 2,
      get value() {
        return this.value_
      },
      set value(val){
        console.log(/*new*/val, /*old*/this.value_)
        this.value_ = val
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: seems correct i'll try thank you ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fa0m9ktd/

Comment: I tried the same things with computed i think it's correct