# Can't prevent change value of v-select component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify to render a combobox, when the user change the value of that combobox I want to display a message asking to confirm the operation, but I'm not able to prevent the change of the value if the user disagree to change the value. I tried with both `input` and `change` events.

Below the HTML:

```
  <v-app>
    <v-container class="indigo lighten-5">
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-select v-model="o.selected" :items="values" @input="inputSelect"></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
```

while the methods that listens for changes is:

```
    inputSelect(val) {
      console.log(val);
      if (confirm(`Do you really want to change the value to ${val}?`)) {
        console.log("ok");
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("ko");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

I created a [pen](https://codepen.io/alessmar/pen/xxONOdZ) to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: this might answer you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197822/vuejs-get-old-value-when-on-change-event

Comment: I updated my [pen](https://codepen.io/alessmar/pen/xxONOdZ), now I'm able to get the old value but I'm not able to prevent the v-select to update the new value (when the user denies to confirm the update), so the model has the old value but the v-select display the new value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not the best solution but after trying to make it work, I found out that the `v-select` always changes the value although the value inside `o.selected` is not changed.

So the workaround is you could reset the `o.selected` first then set the old value back to `o.selected`. I added `setTimeout()` to give it a wait before the code set the old value back.

```js
  inputSelect(val) {
      // store the old value to this variable first
      let oldVal = this.o.selected

      if (confirm(`Do you really want to change to ${val}?`)) {
        this.o.selected = val;
      } else {
        // reset value to whatever value you want
        this.o.selected = '';
        // set timeout here, if no set timeout so the code on the line above will be useless
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.o.selected = oldVal;
        }, 100)
      }
      this.$forceUpdate();  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a better way of preventing a change arbitrarily with something like so:

Remove the listener from the v-select it self and add it to the template

```
<v-select :value="o.selected" :items="values" ref="aRef">
   <template v-slot:item="props">
        <v-list-item v-bind="props.attrs" @click="inputSelect(props.item)">
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                    <span>{{ props.item }}</span>
                </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>

inputSelect(selectedVal) {
  if (confirm(`Do you really want to change the value to ${selectedVal}?`)) {
    this.o.selected = selectedVal; // set the value manually
    this.$refs.aRef.blur() // close the dropdown
  } else {
    this.$refs.aRef.blur() // just close the dropdown without setting the value
  }
}
```