# How to capture previous value of optionset field onchange?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have an optionset field in an entity, I want to fire a JavaScript method on this field change. I want to capture the old value of the field on the change. I've got a solution which gets the old value on form load, but this doesn't work on multiple changes.

Comment: Can you out codes for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

This has to be solved by our own code implementation. Store the attribute value on form load in a variable, keep the new value in that variable on every change, so you can use that in `onChange` handler. At the end of business validation inside handler put that new value in variable if success or revert to old value if failed.

```
var previousValue;

function onFormLoad(){
    previousValue = formContext.getAttribute("fieldname").getValue();
}

function onFieldChange(){
if(myBusinessValidationSucceeds){
    previousValue = formContext.getAttribute("fieldname").getValue();
}
}
```

[Idea 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910161/7920473) and [Idea 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4076770/7920473)