# In my text box, when I type 123 and edit as 1-23, I need to trigger a separate api call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

In my text box, when I type 123 and edit as 1-23, I need to trigger a separate api call and for 123 I need to do separate api call, but right now its capturing the onChange api call. when ever I enter dash between numbers I should call another api, but its calling the same api in on change

I found this links but nothing helping me
[How to get old Value with onchange() event in text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909992/how-to-get-old-value-with-onchange-event-in-text-box)

Can you tell me how to fix it?

I'm providing my code snippet and sandbox below. All my code is present inside `Button.js` which is inside the containers folder:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-ardinghelli-zvco8

```or-tag-here
function useHackerNews(props) {
  const channel = useSelector(state => state.channel);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getPosts = channel => dispatch(fetchPosts(channel));
  const getAlert = () => dispatch(displayAlert());

  document.onmouseup = () => {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
  };

  const onKeyDown = e => {
    console.log("e.keyCode", e.keyCode);

    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      console.log("delete---->", e.target.value);
      getPosts(channel);
      if (e.target.value === "") {
        console.log("onKeyDown delete empty value--->", e.target.value);
        fetchSearch(channel);
      }
    }
  };
  const onMouseUp = e => {
    console.log("onMouseUp e.keyCode", e.keyCode);
    if (window.getSelection().toString().length > 0) return;

    if (e.target.value === "") {
      console.log("onMouseUp delete empty value--->", e.target.value);
      fetchSearch(channel);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <InputBase
        // className={classes.input}
        placeholder="Search Google Maps"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search Google Maps" }}
        onChange={e => {
          if (e.target.value == "") {
            return;
          }

          console.log("onChange e.target.value--->", e.target.value);
          getPosts(channel);
        }}
        onKeyDown={() => {
          // getPosts(channel);
          onKeyDown();
        }}
        onMouseUp={() => {
          // getPosts(channel);
          onMouseUp();
        }}

        //onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        //   onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ... fix what? Can you please be more clear? What all this code does? Why what it does is wrong?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov when ever I enter dash between numbers I should call another api, but its calling the same api in on change :(

Comment: That'd be because you never check whether the entered value has dashes or not. What have you tried to solve your problem? Also, an improved [mcve] would be really helpful, instead of basically a full app that you've linked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need, the solution is here -> https://codepen.io/thyago-luciano/pen/BaBwQBz

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ></input>
</div>
```

JS

```
// variables
var input = document.querySelector("input");

// events
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
  const value = this.value
  if (value.includes("-")) {
    console.log(`call rest API 1 to ${value}`)
    // redirect to API 1
  } else {
    // redirect to API 2
    console.log(`call rest API 2 to ${value}`)
  }
};
```